# how do i parse this xml with jaxb...no field name but nested class

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb

i have this kind of line in an xml file, my problem is to extract "string"

```
    <CONTAINER>
        <FIELD1>string<FIELD2>string2</FIELD2></FIELD>
        <FIELD1>......
    </CONTAINER>
```

if i build a thing like

```
class Container{
     List<String> str;
}
```

i get empty results! instead if i do

```
class Container{
       List<Field> item;
}

class Field{

    String data;
    Field2 f2;
}

class Field2{
    @xmlvalue
    String val;
}
```

i can get the string inside filed2 but not inside field 1

Comment: Looks fine, you just have a text node.

Comment: nope, because if i try to extract the field ILR or LITERAL as a String I obtain empty fields since inside them there is <SENSE> or <TYPE> but on the other side if iI create the class LITERAL I recover the information inside SENSE but i miss the other one...

Comment: This is the basic structure of XML `<parent>text<child/>text</parent>`; the `text` part is identical to `<child>` but its called a "text node". You just need to configure your JAXB `class` correctly to accept both.

Comment: i edited the thing maybe i will be  clearer

Comment: See the duplicate - this question is answered fully there.